# Slow gains in compiling functions

Tags: distributions, compile

I am obtaining slow gains in compiling a function, and would like to ask if there is something I am obviously missing.

The function I intend to speed up has the form:

```
Times@@Table[
        PDF[NormalDistribution[.2, 1], r]  / CDF[NormalDistribution[.2, 1],r],
        {r, 1, 100000}]
```

where in large evaluations the number of elements in the table, and the parameters of the Normal distribution, may change.

This way of evaluating will return a result with a timing of around 8.1 seconds.

I am compiling this function as:

```
t1 = Compile[{{r, _Real, 0}},
      PDF[NormalDistribution[.2, 1], r]  / CDF[NormalDistribution[.2, 1], r], 
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];

t2 = Compile[{{rr, _Real, 1}},
      Times@@t1[rr]];
```

and then invoking

```
t2[Table[r, {r, 1, 100000}]
```

In this case, I get a timing of around 6 seconds - an improvement, but not what I expected. I don't see any MainEvaluate calls. Is there anything obvious I am missing?

Comment: Wait a minute, you don't see `MainEvaluate` in `CompilePrint[t1]`? Did these functions recently become compilable...? I'm on 10.0.2 and `CompilePrint[t1]` has 5 lines for me, two of which are `MainEvaluate` :p

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, same result on 11.0.1 - I think fred is mistaken.

Comment: @SimonWoods, thanks for verifying. fred, that explains the lack of speedup of course.

Comment: Hi all - you are actually both right, my apologies. If I type `"CompiledFunctionTools``CompilePrint[t1]"` I only see the instruction; If I call `Needs["CompiledFunctionTools"]` first, I see them. My inexperience on Compile hits again.  [the inverted accent is not showing well in the in-line code above]

Comment: You should also note that compiled code can only deal with machine numbers and your result is 72 trillion orders of magnitude smaller than the smallest machine real.

Comment: @SimonWoods, thank you. Numbers in the example were totally made up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the PDF and CDF of a normal distribution can be expressed analytically as a function of `Erfc`, you can already speed up your calculation by avoiding the PDF and CDF calculation / lookup at every step:

```
f[mu_, sigma_] = 
 PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma], r] / CDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma], r]
```

[image: result]

```
Times @@ Table[f[.2, 1.], {r, 1, 100000}]

(*Out: 3.3929765235*10^-72383065132319 *)
```

This is already significantly faster than the compiled version:

```
Times @@ Table[f[.2, 1.], {r, 1, 100000}]; // RepeatedTiming

(* Out: {2.7, Null} *)
```

An alternative formulation, using the `Listable` properties of the functions involved, would be:

```
f2[mu_, sigma_][r_] = 
 PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma], r] / CDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma], r]

Times @@ f2[0.2, 1][Range[100000]]; // RepeatedTiming

(* Out: {1.164, Null} *)
```

Of course, the results are all the same:

```
Times @@ Table[
  PDF[NormalDistribution[.2, 1], r]/CDF[NormalDistribution[.2, 1], r],
  {r, 1, 100000}
  ];
Times @@ f2[0.2, 1][Range[100000]];
Times @@ Table[f[.2, 1.], {r, 1, 100000}];

%%% == %% == %

(* Out: True *)
```

Comment: This - plus the comments above on the MainEvaluate calls - is very helpful. I have embedded everything into a single compiled function that makes is very fast now. Will try to update the code above.

Comment: @fred Something probably got lost in your code when copy-pasting. Try to enclose the code in comments inside backticks `like this`. I would also urge you to write your own answer combining the insight you gained.

Answer (score 5):

Following the suggestions above, here's my improved version.

I have found that coding `Erfc` directly eliminates the MainEvaluate and makes everything remarkably fast. This my improved code:

```
t3 = Compile[{{rr, _Real, 1}},
        Times @@ Table[
              (Exp[-((.2 + rr[[f]])/1)^2] ((2/\[Pi])^(1/2))  )/
                      (1 Erfc[(.2 - rr[[f]])/(1 2^0.5)]),
          {f, 1, 100000}]
  ];
```

Comment: Fred, Thank you for sharing your solution. Unfortunately, however, I can't seem to get your code to work. Can you show a use example for `t3`?

Comment: Sure, I should have been more clear. 
In my context, the tensor `rr` has the same length as the table inside the `Compile` function. 
As an example, the instructions `x=Table[0.2,{i,1,100000}]` and `t3[x]` work.